# Rails 5 - Creating two new Models Inheriting from a base Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance

Lets say that I have an `User` model with its attributes (first_name, last_name, etc) and I want to create two new models `Teacher` and `Student`.

They will inherit the `User` model attributes, and also, they will have specific attributes. For instance, the `Student` model will have a `file` attribute, and the `Teacher` model will have `subject` attribute.

I was reading about STI (Single Table Inheritance) and Polymorphic relationships.

What should I look for to accomplish this? Do you have any example to show?

Comment: Have you tried googling [multi table inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=rails+multi+table+inheritance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Answer (score 1):

If you create an attribute called "type" on your `users` table, Rails will automatically assume you want to implement STI. Then, creating Teacher and Student models is as simple as extending the User class. The name of the child class will automatically be inserted into the type column and used to filter queries as you would expect.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**teacher.rb**

```
class Teacher < User
end
```

**student.rb**

```
class Student < User
end
```

With STI, you place all of the columns that either model will use in the same table and simply ignore (default to null) the ones that don't apply in any give situation.

A polymorphic relationship allows two or more tables to fill the same association. If you want to use three different tables but ensure that a User has either a Teacher *or* a Student, that could be modeled as a polymorphic `belongs_to`. The downside is that you would need to get back to the User model to access the shared information, i.e. `teacher.user.first_name`.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having columns with null values in the `Users` table... Maybe I will go with the Polymorphic way. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have found this gem that looks like what I am looking for. I have played with it a little and it does work for me.

https://github.com/krautcomputing/active_record-acts_as

So, for my case I have added to the Gemfile:

`gem 'active_record-acts_as'`

Then:

`$ bundle`

These are my migrations:

```
# 20171202142824_create_users.rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.date :birth_date
      t.string :dni
      t.string :cuil
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.string :address
      t.string :postal_code
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :country
      t.actable # This is important!
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# 20171202142833_create_students.rb
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :file
      # Look, there is no timestamp.
      # The gem ask for it to be removed as it uses the User's timestamp
    end
  end
end

# 20171202142842_create_teachers.rb
class CreateTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :teachers do |t|
      # Look, there is no timestamp.
      # The gem ask for it to be removed as it uses the User's timestamp
    end
  end
end
```

These are my models:

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  actable
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  def full_name
    [last_name.upcase, first_name].join(', ')
  end
end

# student.rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as :user
  validates_presence_of :file
end

# teacher.rb
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as :user
end
```

Now, with all that set, you can simply create a new Student and a new Teacher doing:

```
Student.create!(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', file: 'A125')
=> #<Student id: 3, file: "A125">


Teacher.create!(first_name: 'Max', last_name: 'Power')
=> #<Teacher id: 1>
```

You have access to all the methods and attributes of the User. For instance:

```
Teacher.last.full_name
=> "POWER, Max"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18132891)

Comment: Done! Code samples added. Thanks!